# SDDM fails when PAM_MOUNT is used

Tags: mount, kubuntu, cifs, pam, sddm

I have a new install of Kubuntu 18.04.1, with user authentication via `sssd` to the company's Microsoft Active Directory.

Every user has a Samba share on `//fileserver6/$USER` and I want to mount it at login time.

I managed to get `pam_mount` configured to mount the share whenever the user logs in, and it was working fine... until I logged out of KDE, and discovered that the sddm-greeter didn't work!

Instead of a login prompt, there's just a black screen with a mouse pointer. In the below `pam_mount.conf.xml`, I can comment out the `<volume>` tag, and log in via `sddm`, then I can uncomment it and log into a terminal session, and the directory is automounted. But I can't have both!

Failing a solution to the problem, I'll happily install another display manager if it works (`lightdm` won't even let me choose a user). *[ETA: `lxdm`* does *work]*

**/etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE pam_mount SYSTEM "pam_mount.conf.xml.dtd">
<!--
    See pam_mount.conf(5) for a description.
-->

<pam_mount>

        <!-- debug should come before everything else,
        since this file is still processed in a single pass
        from top-to-bottom -->

<debug enable="0" />

        <!-- Volume definitions -->
<volume user="*" fstype="cifs" server="fileserver6" path="%(USER)" 
        mountpoint="/media/%(USER)/p" options="cruid=%(USER),sec=krb5" />

        <!-- pam_mount parameters: General tunables -->

<luserconf name=".pam_mount.conf.xml" />

<!-- Note that commenting out mntoptions will give you the defaults.
     You will need to explicitly initialize it with the empty string
     to reset the defaults to nothing. -->
<mntoptions allow="nosuid,nodev,loop,encryption,fsck,nonempty,allow_root,allow_other" />
<!--
<mntoptions deny="suid,dev" />
<mntoptions allow="*" />
<mntoptions deny="*" />
-->
<mntoptions require="nosuid,nodev" />

<!-- requires ofl from hxtools to be present -->
<logout wait="0" hup="no" term="no" kill="no" />


        <!-- pam_mount parameters: Volume-related -->

<mkmountpoint enable="1" remove="true" />

</pam_mount>
```

**/etc/pam.d/sddm**

```
auth    requisite       pam_nologin.so
auth    required        pam_succeed_if.so user != root quiet_success

@include common-auth
-auth   optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
-auth   optional        pam_kwallet.so
-auth   optional        pam_kwallet5.so

@include common-account

session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so close
session optional        pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session required        pam_limits.so
session required        pam_loginuid.so
@include common-session
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so open
-session optional       pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
-session optional       pam_kwallet.so auto_start
-session optional       pam_kwallet5.so auto_start

@include common-password
session required        pam_env.so
session required        pam_env.so envfile=/etc/default/locale
```

**/etc/pam.d/sddm-greeter**

```
auth    required        pam_permit.so
@include common-account
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so close
session optional        pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session required        pam_limits.so
session required        pam_loginuid.so
@include common-session
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so open

password        required pam_deny.so
session required        pam_env.so
session required        pam_env.so envfile=/etc/default/locale
```

**/etc/pam.d/common-session**

```
session [default=1]                     pam_permit.so
session requisite                       pam_deny.so
session required                        pam_permit.so
session optional                        pam_umask.so
session required        pam_unix.so 
session optional                        pam_sss.so 
session optional        pam_mount.so 
session optional        pam_systemd.so 
session optional                        pam_mkhomedir.so
```

**/etc/pam.d/common-auth**

```
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_sss.so use_first_pass
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
auth    optional        pam_mount.so 
auth    optional                        pam_cap.so
```

**/etc/pam.d/common-password**

```
password        requisite                       pam_pwquality.so retry=3
password        [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok try_first_pass sha512
password        sufficient                      pam_sss.so use_authtok
password        requisite                       pam_deny.so
password        required                        pam_permit.so
password        optional        pam_mount.so disable_interactive
password        optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced a similar issue, too, on a fresh install of debian testing (buster), with **sddm 0.18.0-1**.

Below is a copy of the message I posted to the *sddm* github issue: https://github.com/sddm/sddm/issues/637.

## tl;dr

Modify the *pam_mount* config in `/etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml`to use the *extended user control*, in order to exclude the *sddm* user from trying to mount the volume:

```
<volume fstype="cifs" server="fileserver6" path="%(USER)" mountpoint="/media/%(USER)/p" options="cruid=%(USER),sec=krb5">
  <not><user>sddm</user></not>
</volume>
```

## Issue description

### symptoms

- Black screen with a mouse pointer, but no possible interaction (left/right mouse click, keyboard)
- TTYs are accessible
- `systemctl stop sddm && startx`allows me to get a working KDE Plasma environment though

### context

- sddm works correctly until I install *pam_mount* (*libpam-mount* for debian), **and** I add a volume in *pam_mount* configuration, such as:

```
<volume fstype="cifs" server="server1.ad.lan" options="domain=MYDOMAIN,vers=3.0" path="data" mountpoint="~/mnt/server1/data" />
```

To be more precise:

- with the default *pam_mount* configuration (ie with no volume), *sddm* will display correctly
- adding a volume to the *pam_mount* config, then `systemctl restart sddm` will trigger the symptoms described above
- removing the volume from *pam_mount* config, then `systemctl restart sddm`, will make *sddm* display correctly again

## Analysis

### logs

In *syslog*:

```
Jan 13 15:12:56 mycomputer sddm[2338]: Greeter starting...
Jan 13 15:12:56 mycomputer sddm[2338]: Adding cookie to "/var/run/sddm/{b73b2904-3de9-46d5-b2ac-a407bd3be089}"
Jan 13 15:12:56 mycomputer sddm-helper[2349]: [PAM] Starting...
Jan 13 15:12:56 mycomputer sddm-helper[2349]: [PAM] Authenticating...
Jan 13 15:12:56 mycomputer sddm-helper[2349]: [PAM] returning.
Jan 13 15:12:56 mycomputer sddm[2338]: (pam_mount.c:568): pam_mount 2.16: entering session stage
Jan 13 15:12:56 mycomputer sddm-helper[2349]: [PAM] Preparing to converse...
Jan 13 15:12:56 mycomputer sddm-helper[2349]: [PAM] Conversation with 1 messages
Jan 13 15:22:53 mycomputer sddm[2338]: Signal received: SIGTERM
```

### humble assumptions... to be checked

As stated in github:

> Same here. I managed to get this working by commenting out:
>
> `@include common-session`
>
> and including all the content of `common-session` except the `pam_mount.so` line at `/etc/pam.d/sddm-greeter`, but when users close their sessions pam_mount is unaware so when they logout their mountpoints don't get unmounted.

The issue seems to occur in `/etc/pam.d/sddm-greeter` , when performing `@include common-session`:

- *pam_mount* tries to mount the volume with the current user, which is *sddm*, and fails

  - in my case, that is perfectly normal, as the current user is the local *sddm* one, and it has no access to my AD domain member server

What I don't understand is:

- when manually logging in with a local user (eg *root*), ie called by `/etc/pam.d/login`: this *pam_mount* failure is ignored, and login can proceed normally
- when called by `/etc/pam.d/sddm-greeter`: the *sddm*  process catches a SIGTERM, and terminates

### questions / possible solution

Is it possible for the *sddm* process to silently ignore errors that occur in `/etc/pam.d/common-session`?
Otherwise, is it possible to modify `/etc/pam.d/sddm-greeter`, by using conditions in `substack`instead of a simple `@include`?
Sorry, I'm no expert with pam, I don't know if this makes sense...

Otherwise, in addition to above proposal, below is another possible workaround:

## Other workaround: modify your *pam_mount* configuration

As stated before, the issue seems to occur because *pam_mount* tries to mount a share using the `sddm`user, which has no credentials for it.

So, basically, we just have to exclude the `sddm` user (and others, if needed), from mounting the share.
This uses the *extended user control* features in *pam_mount* ([link](http://pam-mount.sourceforge.net/pam_mount.conf.5.html#12)).

So, instead of defining the volume as below in `/etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml`:

```
<volume fstype="cifs" server="server1.ad.lan" options="domain=MYDOMAIN,vers=3.0" path="data" mountpoint="~/mnt/server1/data" />
```

We can write (3 variants, adapt to your needs):

### Variant 1: allow only a given range of UIDs

```
<volume fstype="cifs" server="server1.ad.lan" options="domain=MYDOMAIN,vers=3.0" path="data" mountpoint="~/mnt/server1/data" uid="5000-999999999" />
```

### Variant 2: exclude a given range of UIDs

```
<volume fstype="cifs" server="server1.ad.lan" options="domain=MYDOMAIN,vers=3.0" path="data" mountpoint="~/mnt/server1/data">
  <not><uid>0-4999</uid></not>
</volume>
```

### Variant 3: exclude the sddm user only

```
<volume fstype="cifs" server="server1.ad.lan" options="domain=MYDOMAIN,vers=3.0" path="data" mountpoint="~/mnt/server1/data">
  <not><user>sddm</user></not>
</volume>
```

## Conclusion

Sorry for this long post, I hope you will find it useful!

Cheers.

Comment: Other possible solution: define volumes per user, in `~/.pam_mount.conf.xml` instead of `/etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml`. This way you will completely bypass the sddm stuff. But I don't know if this is applicable in your situation?

Comment: Thanks much for that. At the moment, the users are me... So, it would be no problem to define volumes per user. But I want to roll this out company-wide, to mount all our standard Windows shares, so I think your Variant 2 is probably the way to go (because not every Linux user is an SDDM user, but LightDM has the same issue). I'll check this out ASAP.

Comment: btw, I wouldn't call this a long post; just a _thorough_ one.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not seeing any errors in the log, but still getting the black screen with sddm. :-(

Comment: Strange... can you confirm you tested all bullet points in part _Issue description_ (both _symptoms_ and _context_)? Maybe you can also try to extend the exclusion range (e.g. users 0-999999999), to check if the issue comes from the _extended user control_ tag, or the volume definition itself?

Comment: Finally I've had a chance to go back to this and realized that the only problem with it is that I used your first example (the TL;DR) and it had left in the `user="*"` attribute which is invalid with extended user controls